# How to add div as hidden with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I update the html with ajax call. I need to add element as hidden and then apply animation:

```
$.ajax({
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
        $(".comments").prepend(data);
        $(".comments .comment-frame:first").slideDown("slow"); // it doesn't work, since element is visible
```

Data added:

```
<div class="comment-frame">
...
</div>
```

I can not modify css to make class `comment-frame` hidden, since I already have other elements on the page with the same class, which should remain visible. So, somehow I should add that `data` as hidden. How can I do it?

Comment: try `$(".comments").prepend(data).hide()`

Comment: is the .comment-frame(you are tyargetting) always first div in your .comments div ?

Comment: Innuendo, that was my first hunch but i'm suspecting that will hide the wrapping element .comments.

Comment: @Innuendo, I've tried to do so - it adds the `data` first and only after that hide it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make a jQuery object out of `data` and `.hide()` it before `.prepend()`ing it to `$(".comments")`.

```
$.ajax({
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
        var $data = $(data).hide();
        $(".comments").prepend($data);
        $(".comments .comment-frame:first").slideDown("slow");
```

Answer (score 6):

Make a wrapper that's hidden when you insert it:

```
$(".comments").prepend('<div style="display:none">'+data+'</div>');
```